# Firebase hosting - The attempt to bind "/%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" in the workspace failed as this URI is malformed

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

The attempt to bind "/%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" in the workspace failed as this URI is malformed.

Getting multiple erros after deploying my project and then going to it online, this is after putting npm run build in the console, then calling firebase deploy and clicking on the link and loading it in chrome, not sure where to start?

[image: erros]

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"